# Get View reference in a custom spinner adapter

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.spinneritem,arrayListWithData);   
      spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Inside the R.layout.spinneritem I have only a TextView. I need to access that TextView to set a custom typeFace to it.

Is there any way I can get a reference to the TextView, so I can set the typeface programmatically to it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom ArrayAdapter and change the typeface inside the

```java
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

or

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

method, based on your needs.

If you need to simply change the font of your TextView, you can follow the Android guide on [How to change font in XML](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html#fonts-in-xml#fonts-in-xml) in the developer site

Comment: Ended using a custom TextView, and applying the typeface in its constructor. Thanks for trying to help, anyway.

Comment: I dont like too much your solution, if you need to use multiple fonts in your app you will end with a lot of boilerplate classes which differs only for TypeFace setup in the constructor...
I updated my answer on how to do it in XML if you need to simply change the font of the TextView and you don't need some advanced TypeFace features